# Meaning of "What is in here?"

Tags: meaning, the-childrens-bach, helen-garner

This passage is from *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

> What is this, thought Vicki. **What is in here?** It is a warehouse, it has no
> walls or rooms. There is a row of windows, each one shaped like an eye
> with its brow raised. There is a TV, a phone on the floor, a bed like a big
> pink cloud. Where does she cook? Where does she wash herself? Where
> will I sleep? Everybody needs a bed. There are no walls or rooms.
>
> Elizabeth turned round and saw her standing there beside her suitcase.
> She was ashamed. She turned down the music.

I search on net and found:

> **In here** means the room or enclosed area (could be a field or something as was rightly pointed out) we're in

Does "What is in here?" mean:

1. What is this enclosed area?
2. What is in this place?

Comment: *What is in here?* means *What is in this place*? This question is more about English than about literature, and so a better place to ask it would have been on ELL.stackexchange (English Language Learners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Shor says [in the comments](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18372/meaning-of-what-is-in-here#comment28344_18372), "What is in here?" means "What is in this place?". This interpretation is confirmed by the next few sentences:

> It is a warehouse, it has no walls or rooms. There is a row of windows, each one shaped like an eye with its brow raised. There is a TV, a phone on the floor, a bed like a big pink cloud.

The antecedent of the beginning "It" is the "here" from the last sentence. Since "It" is the warehouse, and Vicki is *in* the warehouse, "here" clearly means the place that Vicki is in. The next two sentences, listing various things that are in the warehouse, are positioned to answer the question "What is in here?". This is further confirmation that the question was asking about what was *in* "here" ("this place"), not simply what the place was.

This is a technique that can be applied to other kinds of readings. If you aren't sure how to interpret a sentence, look at the sentences around it. Usually, one interpretation of the sentence will make more sense given the context. Here we saw that a question which is asking about what was "in" Vicki's surroundings made the most sense when considering the next few sentences.